# Visual Studio debugger - How to jump to last iteration of a loop with a dynamic termination condition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am looking for a way to jump to the last iteration of a loop with a dynamic termination condition.

Consider the following model

```cpp
LoopManager loopManager(/* params */)
for (; loopManager.MustKeepIterating() && loopManager.foo() /* && ... */; loopManager.Increment())
{
    /* ... */
    loopManager.Update();
}
```

In this scenario, I can't just loop until `n-1` where `n` is the termination valued condition, because the termination condition is dynamic by depending on the body of the function.

What would be interesting or elegant ways to jump the last iteration in this loop before it gets terminated, as to investigate the functions in the body, at that last iteration? I need to investigate the last iteration, but there are thousands of iterations in my case.

Comment: the question is unclear because the condition depends on side effects of methods called, but no definition is revealed.

Comment: also what is `n` ?

Comment: Edit the code to add an `if` statement testing for the iteration being the last one, then set a breakpoint inside the body of the `if`. Most debuggers (for example `gdb`) also support conditional breakpoints, so you can add a breakpoint in your loop that will only trigger on some condition that is only true on the last loop iteration.

Comment: In `loopManager` add breakpoint(s) where it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model needs to be modified to hit the break point:

```
LoopManager loopManager(/* params */);
auto var =loopManager.MustKeepIterating() && loopManager.foo() ;
for (; var; loopManager.Increment())// add conitional break point this line. Expression e.g.: var== false
{
    /* ... */
    loopManager.Update();
    var=loopManager.MustKeepIterating() && loopManager.foo() /* && ... */
}
```